# Android Client didn't get a message

Tags: android, sockets, client

i am pretty new to android and java programming. I am programming a server client connection. My PC shall be the server and my android smartphone shall be the client. The server works great. I can send a message from the client to the server, but I can't send a message from the server to the client. When i am doing this the client crushes and closes itself. I really hope that anybody can help me with my big issue.

Here is my Activity:

```
package com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
EditText textOut;
TextView textIn;
TextView problems;
Button send;
private TCPClient myTcpClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView textIn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

    // connect to the server
    new connectTask().execute("");

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String message = editText.getText().toString();

            //sends the message to the server
            if (myTcpClient != null) {
                myTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        myTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {

            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        myTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we don't add the message received from server
        //here i try to write the incomming message into a textVie
        textIn.setText(values[0]);
    }
}
}
```

and here is my TCPClient class:

```
package com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TCPClient {

private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.2.107"; //your computer IP address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;

PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;

/**
 * constructor of the class. OnMessageReceived listens for the messages 
 * received from server
 */
public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient() {
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {
    mRun = true;

    try {
        // here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {
            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");
            Log.e("TCP Client", "C:Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages send by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            //after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP", "C:Error", e);
    }
}

/*
 * Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message must be
 * implemented in the MyActivity class at on asynckTask doInBackground
 */
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

Finally here you can see my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Textausgabe" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/Senden" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/EinkommenderText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my LogCat:

> 12-30 16:36:37.340: I/dalvikvm(548): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>
> 12-30 16:36:37.560: I/dalvikvm(548): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>
> 12-30 16:36:37.740: I/dalvikvm(548): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>
> 12-30 16:36:37.790: I/dalvikvm(548): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>
> 12-30 16:36:38.350: D/gralloc_goldfish(548): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>
> 12-30 16:36:38.630: I/dalvikvm(548): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>
> 12-30 16:36:38.650: I/dalvikvm(548): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>
> 12-30 16:36:39.721: E/TCP Client(548): C: Connecting...
>
> 12-30 16:36:39.981: E/TCP Client(548): C: Sent.
>
> 12-30 16:36:39.990: E/TCP Client(548): C:Done.
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.034: D/AndroidRuntime(548): Shutting down VM
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.034: W/dalvikvm(548): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
>   (group=0x409c01f8)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei.MyActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MyActivity.java:72)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   com.example.sercerclient2zweidreidrei.MyActivity$connectTask.onProgressUpdate(MyActivity.java:1)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:618)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at 
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.051: E/AndroidRuntime(548):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
>   Method)
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.752: I/dalvikvm(548): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
>
> 12-30 16:38:59.900: I/dalvikvm(548): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I hope you can find my mistake.

Comment: You might want to think about using GCM to deliver your messages to your device. Also adding some logging code and posting the results will help people answer you.

Comment: I added my LogCat and hope that someone can find my mistake there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an AsyncTask task in an Activity to establish a TCP connection. So as soon as the connection is established the message is sent and your AsyncTask task finishes and you close the TCP connection.

You should use a stand-alone service instead of an Activity to keep the connection open.

Comment: [link] (http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.de/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html)  There i found it in a similar way and it worked. But in my app i wont have this list view just a TextView. Isn't there the possibility to show the incomming message in a TextView?

Comment: Of course there are several possibilities. You have to maintain your established connection. Are you sur to maintain your connection? In the example you cite above, the connection is maintained.

Comment: Ok. That is not really the answers i wanted to hear but ok. If this is the only way. My connection also crushes when I switch my phone to the horizontally mode. Can this issue caused by using the AsyncTask?

Comment: No this is happend because you manage the life-cycle of your connection by your Activity. So when you switch your phone, the activity destroyed -> finish asynctask, and a new Activity created. So to avoid this, you should manage your connection with a service or by your application level.

Comment: Do you maybe have a code example for me how to write a service? And i don't understand what you mean with the application level. I looked up for this, but i didn't understand how this works and what this is.

Comment: create a service is as easy as creating an activity. Just take a look at ANdroid dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I read that a sevice didn't open a other thread. Can i have threre the same problem as when i create a connection in the mainactivity? So, do i have to create a new thread for this service or not?

Comment: of course you can use an asynctask or a new thread  from service. The only restriction is you must call the asynctask from the main thread. Make your TCP connection from a stand-alone service and use "Otto" (an Event Bus) to communicate the result to your activities.